# ways to get artist name and track name from youtube title

Tags: python, parsing

I'm working on a project which requires me to get the `name` of the main artist (if there are more than one artist mentioned in the title) and the track name from a youtube music video title. I thought of working with youtube dl but it doesn't work anymore.

If you've worked on a similar project before. Please drop suggestions.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It might be an idea to do some web-scrapping, request the html of the youtube music video page, then use a python library like lxml to find the specific data you require

Comment: There's already an [unofficial YouTube Music API](https://ytmusicapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which can get all the info you want, maybe that'd help so you wouldn't have to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @RandomDavis thanks a lot, ill check it out for sure.

Comment: @Sam thanks for suggestion but scraping if i have like 100 songs will take a long time. So that is not an option.Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Feel free to upvote [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/181347378) if you want to see this feature added.

Comment: @CardinalSystem I would like to get that thing implemented but i dont think such a huge thing can be made in an instant it could take months or even years. But i did star it though

Comment: I guess that if scraping is a problem, then my solution may not be well-suited but I'll *advertise* it anyway: [I have answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74652266) the same question on StackOverflow, let me know if it doesn't fit your needs.